# Subscribing to a dependency property on a user control in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, reactiveui

I'm trying to use ReactiveUI to subscribe to changes in a dependency property 
on a UserControl.

I saw the technique described in another stack overflow answer([Combine dependency properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196302/combine-dependency-properties)) but I'm going wrong with the implementation somewhere. Even in the simple case below, I can't get the subscription to fire when the dependency property changes.

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

```
public partial class AutoCompleteBox : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem",typeof(object),typeof(AutoCompleteBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata{BindsTwoWayByDefault = true});

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public AutoCompleteBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();               
        this.WhenAny(m=>m.SelectedItem,m=>m.Value)
            .Subscribe(_=>
            Console.WriteLine("Selected Item Changed!"));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I'm using ReactiveUI version 4.4.2.0

On further investigation, the subscribe call does appear to work when I use the user control in my main project, just not in the small project that I'm using for testing it. I'm not sure what the difference could be.